# Django - ValueError on HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, http-redirect

i have this view: http://dpaste.com/661912/ on which i have an error: ValueError at /fattura/save/ ... the view didn't return an HttpResponse object. i dont know why since i have on the same project another really similar view: http://dpaste.com/661913/ that works correctly.

this is the urlconf:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url


# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',


   ...
    url(r'^soggetto/save/','gpf1.views.anagrafica_save'),
  ...
    url(r'^fattura/save/','gpf1.views.fattura_save'),


    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

also here there's no big differences.
any help?

thanks

Comment: does your stack trace tell you which line is causing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at that view, and work out what is returned if either the request is not a POST, or the form is not valid. Then you will have enough information to answer the question by yourself.